Вход в телеграм аккаунт по номеру, с помощью pyrogram
Почему у меня возникает ошибка Unresolved reference 'API' в коде, в API.TelegramDesktop.Genera?
async def test(phone_number):
    api_id = API.TelegramDesktop.Generate().api_id
    api_hash = API.TelegramDesktop.Generate().api_hash
    app = Client("my_account", phone_number=phone_number, api_id=api_id, 
api_hash=api_hash)
    await app.connect()
    sCode = await app.send_code(phone_number)
    code = input('Enter auth code: ')
    await app.sign_in(phone_number, sCode.__dict__['phone_code_hash'], code)
    await app.send_message('me', 'test')

