Вход в телеграм аккаунт по номеру телефона, с помощь pyrogram
У меня выходит ошибка, когда я пиши этот код, ошибка происходит в API.TelegramDesktop.Generate().api_id
Ошибка: Unresolved reference 'API'
async def test(phone_number):
    api_id = API.TelegramDesktop.Generate().api_id
    api_hash = API.TelegramDesktop.Generate().api_hash
    app = Client("my_account", phone_number=phone_number, api_id=api_id, 
api_hash=api_hash)
    await app.connect()
    sCode = await app.send_code(phone_number)
    code = input('Enter auth code: ')
    await app.sign_in(phone_number, sCode.__dict__['phone_code_hash'], code)
    await app.send_message('me', 'test')


зачем дубль? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1601698
